# Need some help writing a "centripetal force" app for physics class

Tags: shiny, shiny-reactivity

I'm fairly new to rshiny. I'm sure my problem is addressed in various documentation, but I'm not finding it.

The centripetal force (physics) depends on mass, velocity, and radius. I want the students to play with all three to see what happens to the force. I'm using sliders for the variables.

But I also want them to explore the relationship between velocity and radius when the force is fixed. For that, I use a checkbox and I try to catch whether the radius slider was moved (in which case update the velocity slider such that the force is fixed) or whether the velocity slider was moved (in which case update the radius slider keeping the force fixed).

This has caused some undesired behavior - moving one slider does update the other slider, but they keep updating and eventually end up all the way to the left, or all the way to the right.

I think when moving all three sliders I want the force output to be reactive, but when the checkbox is checked I don't want the force output to be reactive. I want it fixed.

I could use some help or hints. Here is my code:

```
library(shiny)

# Define UI for application that explores centripetal acceleration
update_svg <- function(radius, velocity) {
    svg <- paste(readLines("images/centripetal-animated.svg"), collapse = "\n")

    # transformations ...
    scale <- round(radius/40, 4)

    dt <- round(2*pi*radius/velocity, 2)
    dy <- round(-36*velocity/62.83/scale, 4)
    a <- velocity^2/radius
    dx <- round(-52.92*a/100/scale, 4)
    x0 <- 148.166664 + dx

    cx <- round((scale - 1)*95.25, 2)
    cy <- round((scale - 1)*100.54166, 2)


    svg <- sub("\\{scale\\}", scale, svg)
    svg <- sub("\\{DY\\}", dy, svg)
    svg <- sub("\\{X0\\}", x0, svg)
    svg <- sub("\\{DX\\}", -dx, svg)
    svg <- sub("\\{DT\\}", dt, svg)
    svg <- sub("\\{CX\\}", -cx, svg)
    svg <- sub("\\{CY\\}", -cy, svg)

    con <- paste0(tempfile("svg"), ".svg")
    writeLines(svg, con)

    con
}

ui <- fluidPage(

    # Application title
    titlePanel("Physics"),

    # Tabset panel
    tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel("Centripetal Acceleration",
            # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
            sidebarLayout(
                sidebarPanel(
                    sliderInput("mass",
                                "Mass (kg):",
                                min = 0,
                                max = 10,
                                value = 5),
                    sliderInput("radius",
                                "Radius (m):",
                                min = 0,
                                max = 60,
                                value = 30),
                    sliderInput("velocity",
                                "Tangential Velocity (m/s):",
                                min = 0,
                                max = 60,
                                value = 30),
                    textOutput("angular"),
                    textOutput("acceleration"),
                    list(textInput("force", "Force (N):", 150), checkboxInput("freeze", "Fix mass & force"))
                ),

                # Show a plot of the generated distribution
                mainPanel(
                    imageOutput("svg")
                )
            )
        )
    )

)

# Define server logic 
server <- function(input, output, session) {
    # if force is fixed, observe change in radius and adjust
    # velocity to maintain fixed acceleration and force.
    observeEvent(input$radius,  {
        if (input$freeze == 1) {
            updateSliderInput(session = session, inputId = "velocity",
                              value = sqrt(as.numeric(input$force)*input$radius/input$mass))
        }
    })

    # if force is fixed, observe change in velocity and
    # adjust radius to maintain fixed acceleration and force.
    observeEvent(input$velocity,  {
        if (input$freeze == 1) {
            updateSliderInput(session = session, inputId = "radius",
                              value = input$mass*input$velocity^2/as.numeric(input$force))
        }
    })

    observe({
        angular <- input$velocity/input$radius
        acceleration <- input$radius*angular^2
        force <- input$mass*acceleration

        output$angular <- renderText(paste0("Angular Velocity: ", signif(angular, 2), " (rad/s)"))
        output$acceleration <- renderText(paste0("Acceleration: ", signif(acceleration, 2), " (m/s^2)"))
        updateTextInput(session ,"force", value = signif(force, 2))

        output$svg <- renderImage(list(src = update_svg(input$radius, input$velocity)))
    })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```